# push and pull effect is not working in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show list above the paragraph in small device and also in extra small device. I uses push-* and pull-* class that are available in bootstrap but its not working. please suggest. Thanks in advance.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12"> 
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris suspendisse viverra eleifend tortor tellus suscipit, etiam bibendum cras posuere pede placerat, velit neque felis. Turpis ut mollis, elit et vestibulum mattis integer aenean nulla. Dignissim neque, nulla neque. Ultrices proin mi urna nibh ut, aenean sollicitudin etiam libero nisl.</p> 
</div>  
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12"> 
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>sse viverra eleifend tortor tellus suscipit</li>
    <li>cras posuere pede placerat, velit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>sse viverra eleifend tortor tellus suscipit</li>
    <li>cras posuere pede placerat, velit</li>
    </ul>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is expected behavior?

Comment: Did you try col-xs-push-6 ?

Comment: yes, i used both col-sm-push-6 and col-xs-push-6. But it is not working.

Comment: Here, You have add push and pull effect for sm(small device). but, You have not define sm(`col-sm-*`) class there. So, it is not working. You need to add `col-sm-6` there. & then check it. Please read carefully for Column ordering - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the list on top on small devices and to the right on medium devices you need to change the order of the elements in the DOM. Then you can use `push` and `pull` to do as you wish

Click the "Full page" button to see...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-6">
            <ul>
                <li>sse viverra eleifend tortor tellus suscipit</li>
                <li>cras posuere pede placerat, velit</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                <li>sse viverra eleifend tortor tellus suscipit</li>
                <li>cras posuere pede placerat, velit</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris suspendisse viverra eleifend tortor tellus suscipit, etiam bibendum cras posuere pede placerat, velit neque felis. Turpis ut mollis, elit et vestibulum mattis integer aenean nulla. Dignissim neque, nulla neque. Ultrices proin mi urna nibh ut, aenean sollicitudin etiam libero nisl.</p>
        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ??? The code is in my answer - Notice the order of the elements. The list comes first